# How to process multiple images at the same time with "cupyx.scipy.ndimage.map_coordinates"

Tags: python, cupy

I need to sample from multiple images by a fixed, pre-computed set of coordinates with in python high performance. Currently, these images are loaded into a cupy array of dimension `[channel,height,width]` on GPU, where each channel represents one image. The pre-computed sampling coordinates is a cupy array of dimension `[2,1,output_height,output_width]`. And I am currently processing each image by a Python for-loop:

```
import cupy as cp
from cupyx.scipy import ndimage

channel = Img.shape[0]  # Number of channels in the input image
ImgT = cp.empty((channel, output_height, output_width, dtype=Img.dtype)  # Store the transformed image
for c in range(channel):
    ImgT[c,:,:] = ndimage.map_coordinates(Img[c,:,:], coordinate, order=1, mode='constant', cval=0.0)
```

However, since the sampling coordinates is the same for each image, is it possible to remove the for-loop, and sample from all the images at once?

I have tried the following two methods:

```
# Method 1
ImgT = ndimage.map_coordinates(Img, coordinate, order=1, mode='constant', cval=0.0)

# Method 2
coordinate_expand = cp.repead(coordinate, channel, axis=1)
ImgT = ndimage.map_coordinates(Img, coordinate_expand , order=1, mode='constant', cval=0.0)
```

Both methods run without errors. But the dimension of the output of the first method is not correct. The output dimension is `[1,output_height,output_width]`, but I expect `[channel,output_height,output_width]`. The output of the second method has dimension `[channel,output_height,output_width]`, but the output image is not correct (very different from the output of the original for-loop).

Is it possible to process multiple images at the same time with "cupyx.scipy.ndimage.map_coordinates"?